# Parent class init is executing during inheritence

Tags: python, oop, python-2.x

One basic question in OOP.

`test.py` file content:

```py
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'INIT of test class'

obj = test()
```

Then I opened another file.

I just inherited from the above test class:

```py
from test import  test

class test1(test):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

So when I run this second file, the `__init__()` from the parent class is executed (the INIT got printed).

I read that I can avoid it by using

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
```

I can overcome this, but my question is why the parent class's init is  executing as I am just importing this class only in my second file. Why is the object creation code executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Importing a module executes all module-level statements, including `obj=test()`.
To avoid this, make an instance only when run as the main program, not when imported:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'INIT of test class'

if __name__ == '__main__':
     obj=test()
```

The problem is not the inheritance but the import. In your case you execute `obj=test()` when importing:

```
from test import test
```

When you import `test`, its name `__name__` is `test`.
But when you run your program on the command line as main program with `python test.py`, its name is `__main__`. So, in the import case, you skip `obj=test()`if you use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     obj=test()
```

Comment: @ Mike Müller Thanks!,  how obj=test() executed since I am importing only the class and this call is outside the class?

Comment: Importing means always executing the whole module. Even when you only selectively get the class with `from xxx import`.

Comment: @ Mike Müller    oh!, In this case if we are importing whole module, whats the difference between selective import and wild import?
 I mean difference  between "from module import A,B"     and  "from module import * " ? or its just readability difference

Comment: `from module import * `clutters you current namespace with all names from `module`. `from module import A, B` only adds `A` and `B` explicitly.

Comment: But why if we are defaultly  importing the whole module , the  class A and B should automatically added to namespace?

Comment: Or does it mean import will do import of the specified module + main function as well as default  ?

Comment: You just execute the whole module as a side effect when doing selective imports.